# Action bar tab inside another action bar tabs

Tags: android, tabs

I need to do an action bar tabs inside another action bar tabs.I seen many tutorials that's all related to create only the action bar tabs.

I am expecting to do an action bar tabs inside another action bar tabs.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8mSy.png)

If I get some tutorial or sample or any other suggestions related to this.It will be helpful to me.Thank you.

Comment: As an alternative you can use ViewPager and SlidingTabStrip (https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabStrip.html)